# Postgres replace an array inside a JSONB field

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table where the `data` field has JSONB type and among many other data I have a `notes` key inside the `data` json value where I store an array of notes.

Each note has (at least) two fields: `title` and `content`.

Sometimes I have to replace the whole list of notes with a different list, but not affecting any other fields inside my json record.

I tried something like this:

   `UPDATE mytable
   SET data = jsonb_set("data", '{notes}', '[{ "title": "foo1" "content": "bar"'}, { "title": "foo2" "content": "bar2"}]', true)
   WHERE id = ?`

And I get an exception (through a js wrapper)
`error: invalid input syntax for type json`

How should I correctly use the `jsonb_set` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a stray single quote and missing commas in your JSON payload

Instead of

```
[{ "title": "foo1" "content": "bar"'}, { "title": "foo2" "content": "bar2"}]
                  ^                ^                    ^
```

it should rather look

```
[{ "title": "foo1", "content": "bar"}, { "title": "foo2", "content": "bar2"}]
```